# iOS: move circle shape view by collision by dragging another?

Tags: ios, collision

I have two UIViews shaped like a circle. (see image).

I am trying to figure out how to make the two views move by collision.
So I am moving one with a touch by changing it's position as I move my finger on it. I want to see the other move as I "push" the one I am moving against the other circle shaped view.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify which part(s) of this you need help with?  Is it the physics of the collision, or the collision detection, or just setting the frame of the non-dragged view?  If you need help with the physics can you clarify whether you want an elastic collision (views "bouncing" off each other) or an inelastic collision (where the pushed view sort of sticks to the pushing view)?

Comment: The first thing I am not sure about is how to set a circle shape path as part the actual shapes that will collide. Usually examples I can find have a standard frame (rectangular frame) but not a path of a certain shape. As far as the physics goes elastic will do.

Comment: look into [UIKit Dynamics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: @cmyr I did, but I couldn't see something that would do for round shapes. What I saw was mainly about rects (rectangular frame).

Comment: Is it necessary that you use UIKit? This sounds like something that might make more sense to do in SceneKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SceneKit did the trick. I created the geometries and then applied physic bodies to each. With the proper physics configuration in the scene they now collide.